# Resharper inserting br tags when pressing return key

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

I'm not sure how this has happened but whenever i press the return key in my HTML/Razor editor window it is inserting a `<br>` tag instead of a new line.

It only does this if i press the return key whilst the cursor is at the end of a tag, such as at the end of this `<div>`.

If my cursor is already on an empty line and i press return it works fine.

I beleive this is related to ReSharper because if i disable ReSharper it works just fine, i have tried all the settings i can think of, as well as resetting all the settings to defaults but still no luck.

- Resharper version 7
- Visual Studio 2012

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a [bug that has been fixed](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-330382) in ReSharper v7.1. Try upgrading to the newer version.